# ERC4626 and slippage

Tags: solidity, erc

The newly introduced [ERC4626 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4626) provides functions for depositing and withdrawing funds to a vault, but it is unclear to me how the designers envisioned adding custom slippage rates from the function method:

> function deposit(uint256 assets, address receiver) public virtual
> returns (uint256 shares);

There's mention that slippage rates *should* be included in the preview functions (e.g., previewDeposit), but what would the best-practice solution look like to add per-interaction slippage with this? My only thoughts here are:

- somehow set-it in a mapping prior to calling the deposit function but that seems unnecessarily cumbersome.
- implement standard slippage of e.g., 3% and add a custom deposit function that does support slippage

In any case, neither of these would be 'standard'.

Answer (score 1):

You can customise the inner workings of the deposit function as you wish. Like adding a standard slippage

```
uint slippage = 100; // = 1% slippage

function deposit(uint256 assets, address receiver) public virtual returns (uint256 shares){
    //... code
    uint amountWithSlippage = amount + (amount / slippage); using amounts under 100 wei would make transaction revert, add an if statement to make this possible
    //... code

}
```

Or add a fucntion where users can edit their slippage themselves

```
mapping(address => uint) slippages;

function setSlippage(uint _slippage) public {
    slippages[msg.sender] = _slippage;

function deposit(uint256 assets, address receiver) public virtual returns (uint256 shares){

     //... code
    uint slippage = slippages[msg.sender];
    uint amountWithSlippage = amount + (amount / slippage);
    //... code
```